# Подскажите Python и СИ в Sublime text

Tags: python, c, sublime-text, текст

Вообщем python я все таки настроила на Sublime text. Теперь другая проблема, как переключить Sublime text на СИ?

File "hello.c", line 2
    void main ()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

***Repl Closed***

Comment: У C не может быть REPL, он возможен только у интерпретируемых языков.

Comment: Ok, как быть?как мне переключиться на СИ(

Comment: Что значит "переключиться на СИ"?

Comment: Как переключить компилятор  pythona на компилятор СИ?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы при нажатии какой-нибудь клавиши выполнялся код С, который вы набрали в редакторе?

Comment: да, я нажимаю CTRL + B, и мне выдает этот текст что выше, а когда код pythonа с этими же клавишами выдает правильный результат

Comment: А почему бы не попробовать использовать компилятор С вместо компилятора Питона? Это как раз и будет "переключиться на СИ".

Comment: у меня установлены и компилятор С и компилятор Питона, только Питон я компилирую сразу в Sublime text, а С приходится через командную строку, теперь вопрос как переключатся внутри программы, чтобы и С так же компилировать в Sublline(до того как питон настроила С работал в Sublime text)

Comment: Не работал с этим редактором, но из общих соображений первым делом надо посмотреть в настройки и связать файлы ".c" с компилятором C.